# XPath Select node from current node value when the two attribute names are the same

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Can anyone help me with this little issue I am having.

The XML

```
<MPN>
    <MTR MSN="AB123456"/>
    <MTR MSN="AB654321"/>
    <MTR MSN="AB654322"/>
    <MTR MSN="AB654323”/>
    <MTR MSN="AB654324"/>
    <JOB JobId="136">
        <JMR MSN="AB123456">
            <JRA DateActionRequiredBy="20090701120012" />
        </JMR>
        <JMR MSN="AB654321">
            <JRA DateActionRequiredBy="20090701100010" />
        </JMR>
    </JOB>
</MPN>
```

I would like to retrieve the DateActionRequiredBy from the JRA element, when the parser is sitting at the MTR Element, only one should be returned.

I have tried.

```
../JOB/JMR[@MSN = @MSN]/JRA/@DateActionRequiredBy
```

which returns **{Dimension:[2]}  NodeSet**, this matches everything due to the @MSN attribute effectively matching itself not the parent.

```
../JOB/JMR[@MSN = ./@MSN]/JRA/@DateActionRequiredBy
```

which returns **{Dimension:[2]}  NodeSet**

I have found a solution but it will require a variable inside every xsl:attribute which doesn't seem right to me.

```
<xsl:variable name="storeMSN" select="@MSN"/>
../JOB/JMR[@MSN = $storeMSN]/JRA/@DateActionRequiredBy
```

which returns
    **20090701120012 Attribute**

This is what i am after, but there must be an easier way to achieve this other than a variable for every attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<MPN>
    <MTR MSN="AB123456"/>
    <MTR MSN="AB654321"/><!-- current node (i.e. context node) -->
    <MTR MSN="AB654322"/>
    <MTR MSN="AB654323”/>
    <MTR MSN="AB654324"/>
    <JOB JobId="136">
        <JMR MSN="AB123456">
            <JRA DateActionRequiredBy="20090701120012" />
        </JMR>
        <JMR MSN="AB654321">
            <JRA DateActionRequiredBy="20090701100010" /><!-- desired node -->
        </JMR>
    </JOB>
</MPN>
```

then you would need to use this XPath:

```
../JOB/JMR[@MSN = current()/@MSN]/JRA/@DateActionRequiredBy
```

Note that this will work in XSLT only, since `current()` is an XSLT function.

You could ease the process by adding an XSL key:

```
<xsl:key name="kJMR" match="JMR" use="@MSN" />
```

and in XPath:

```
key('kJMR', @MSN)/JRA/@DateActionRequiredBy
```

---

Explanation why your tries don't work as expected. Both

- `../JOB/JMR[@MSN = @MSN]/JRA/@DateActionRequiredBy`
- `../JOB/JMR[@MSN = ./@MSN]/JRA/@DateActionRequiredBy`

compare `@MSN` with itself - an operation that can never fail. This way you always get all possible nodes.

Within a predicate, the XPath context always is the node that you apply the predicate to. The `current()` function is there to provide you with the XSLT context.

Comment: yes current() was the missing piece in the puzzle.  Thanks ;-)